# Get /me and /friends in same query possible? facebook-graph-api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to combine `/me` and `/friends` queries into one?

I tried `/?ids=me,friends` but obv it didn't work, any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `me?fields=id,name,friends`